# Hook into a unknown function in a dll using C#

Tags: c#, dll, hook

Is it possible to find out what functions are available in an arbitrary dll file and then call these functions using C# interop services.

Comment: Are you trying to do this at runtime? Why?

Comment: I have been trying to write a shell extention for Microsofts Skydrive to basically have it show up as a drive in Explorer. I have been having a lot of difficulties trying to write the scarper. I dont know what is wrong. I cant get my program to login to windows live even though I am passing all the right cookies and other headers in the request. There are other solutions out there like SDExplorer so I hoped to use one of their DLLs in my own version.

Comment: BTW its only for personal use so I wouldn't be infringing on any copyrights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can analyze the exported functions of any native module (DLL or EXE) using tools such as [dumpbin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c.aspx). Once you have the signatures of the exported functions, you can write P/Invoke wrappers for any of them you wish.

Alternatively, you can use a tool like the [P/Invoke Interop Assistant](http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/) to automagically do the grunt work for you.

However, all of that relies upon the native module having listed the functions you're trying to call in its export table. If what you're looking to hook into is not actually exported, then you will have to resort to old-fashioned spelunking with GetProcAddress, etc.

Comment: but how can I get the function signature using dumpbin? it's just printing me the names of the exported functions but no signature

Comment: It depends. You're getting into pretty specific hackery at that point. If it's a C++ module that exported the methods, then /SYMBOLS should dump out the parameters. However they'll likely be mangled.

Try using a tool like Dependency Walker (depends.exe) to demangle them for you. Ideally you can find a function reference in docs somewhere so you don't have to mess with this, unless you just enjoy the process.

Comment: I would definitely try using the P/Invoke Interop Assistant if you haven't yet. It is designed to (when it can) derive all of the function names and parameters for you.

Answer (score 1):

If the .dll is a managed assembly, then you can use the classes in `System.Reflection` to find and run arbitrary methods.

If it's a native Win32 dll, then you have a much harder road to hoe: you have to P/Invoke the Win32 APIs `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` and call the functions you want through an unsafe pointer.

Comment: They are native dlls. I wish it was managed then I could just use Reflector to see how its done

Answer (score 1):

So if the DLL you are refering to is a native DLL with C functione exports this is going to be range from easy to very difficult.

Easy: If you have the DLL and a C header file and even better with some documentation so that you know what arguments the exported functions expect, what calling convention is used. No problem use the .NET Interop services (PInvoke) as others have mentioned and call the functions you need.

Very Hard: If all you have is the DLL, you can discover the exports using `DumpBin /exports filename.dll` but then you are left with disasembling the code to try and determine the calling convention and what possible values and types the function expects. To be honest, if this stuff is Greek to you then this is not Very hard, it is borderline impossible without huge but interesting learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

See P/Invoke: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinvoke

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dependency Walker to find the exported functions in the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

If its an unmanaged, native dll, you will need to use a program such as dumpbin or PE Explorer. Both programs will show the export section of the dll.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about "arbitrary" dlls, but for .net assemblies, there's an excellent utility called "Reflector" that will tell you what functions are inside.  you can then call them with reflection.  I'm not familiar with "interop services".

Comment: Yes I am aware of the great little utility called Reflector. But these are native dlls